# How to instantly show text on a web page?

Tags: python, node.js

I have a python code and I call it in nodejs.
The python code will print a sentence at different stage. After each print in python there is a `sys.stdout.flush()`.
Now I use nodejs python shell

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  flag = req.body.flag;
  options = {
    mode: 'text',
    args: [ '--flag='+flag]
  };

  pyshell = new PythonShell(myPythonScriptPath, options)

  pyshell.on('message', function (message) {   
    resultText = `It's ${flag} degrees in ${message}!`;
    res.render('index', {result: resultText, error: null});
    console.log(message);
  })
})
```

It returned only one sentence and after that there was an error:
`Error: Can't set headers after they are sent`.

This worked fine if I do not use

```
resultText = `It's ${flag} degrees in ${message}!`;
res.render('index', {result: resultText, error: null});
```

and only use terminal.
BUT it fails with a web page.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From community wiki's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7086621/1368534):

The `res` object in Express is a subclass of [Node.js's `http.ServerResponse`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http.ServerResponse) ([read the http.js source](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http.ServerResponse)). You are allowed to call `res.setHeader(name, value)` as often as you want until you call `res.writeHead(statusCode)`. After `writeHead`, the headers are baked in and you can only call `res.write(data)`, and finally `res.end(data)`.

The error "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent." means that you're already in the Body or Finished state, but some function tried to set a header or statusCode. When you see this error, try to look for anything that tries to send a header after some of the body has already been written. For example, look for callbacks that are accidentally called twice, or any error that happens after the body is sent.

Comment: I was not using res.writeHead, I was using res.render.  By the way how can I make this coding correct.